# Support for Database testing in NUnit?

Tags: database, nunit

I'm aware of the fact that database testing (CRUD) can be considered out of NUnits scope, since it's not quite unit testing, but nevertheless :

Is there any standard way in NUnit for database testing?

Something in the lines of rolling back transactions made, or any other solution I cannot come up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [XtUnit](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2004/10/05/Introducing_3A00_-XtUnit-.-An-Unofficial-Unit-Testing-Extensibility-Framework-_2D00_-Add-new-attributes-to-NUnit-or-MbUnit-easily_2100_.aspx) but I don't know if it works with NUnit 2.5

MbUnit has a built-in `[Rollback]`, you might want to use MbUnit instead of NUnit for database testing.